# Error in OpenCV Edgeboxes sample program

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tried the new OpenCV edge boxes implementation. I ran the edgeboxes_demo program from OpenCV ximgproc samples and it causes the following assertion failure.

> OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)(i1 *
>   DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())) in
>   cv::Mat::at, file
>   C:\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp,
>   line 1107

Tried to follow the error and found that it was caused by the prepDataStructsfuntion of the edge boxes class. The code of the function is given below.

I have tried changing

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) _sDone.at<int>(0,i) = -1;
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) _sDone.at<int>(i,0) = -1;
```

but the problem remains.

```
void EdgeBoxesImpl::prepDataStructs(Mat &edgeMap)
{
    int y, x, i;

    // create _segIImg
    Mat E1 = Mat::zeros(w, h, DataType<float>::type);

    for (i=0; i < _segCnt; i++)
    {
      if (_segMag[i] > 0) E1.at<float>(_segP[i].x, _segP[i].y) = _segMag[i];
    }

    _segIImg = Mat::zeros(w+1, h+1, DataType<float>::type);
    _magIImg = Mat::zeros(w+1, h+1, DataType<float>::type);

    for (x=1; x < w; x++)
    {
      const float *e_ptr = edgeMap.ptr<float>(x);
      const float *e1_ptr = E1.ptr<float>(x);
      const float *si0_ptr = _segIImg.ptr<float>(x);
      float *si1_ptr = _segIImg.ptr<float>(x+1);
      const float *mi0_ptr = _magIImg.ptr<float>(x);
      float *mi1_ptr =_magIImg.ptr<float>(x+1);
      for (y=1; y < h; y++)
      {
        // create _segIImg
        si1_ptr[y+1] = e1_ptr[y] + si0_ptr[y+1] + si1_ptr[y] - si0_ptr[y];
        float e = e_ptr[y] > _edgeMinMag ? e_ptr[y] : 0;
        // create _magIImg
        mi1_ptr[y+1] = e +mi0_ptr[y+1] + mi1_ptr[y] - mi0_ptr[y];
      }
    }

    // create remaining data structures
    int s = 0;
    int s1;

    _hIdxs.resize(h);
    _hIdxImg = Mat::zeros(w, h, DataType<int>::type);
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        s = 0;
        _hIdxs[y].push_back(s);
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            s1 = _segIds.at<int>(x, y);
            if (s1 != s)
            {
                s = s1;
                _hIdxs[y].push_back(s);
            }
            _hIdxImg.at<int>(x, y) = (int)_hIdxs[y].size() - 1;
        }
    }

    _vIdxs.resize(w);
    _vIdxImg = Mat::zeros(w, h, DataType<int>::type);
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        s = 0;
        _vIdxs[x].push_back(s);
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            s1 = _segIds.at<int>(x, y);
            if (s1 != s)
            {
                s = s1;
                _vIdxs[x].push_back(s);
            }
            _vIdxImg.at<int>(x, y) = (int)_vIdxs[x].size() - 1;
        }
    }

    // initialize scoreBox() data structures
    int n = _segCnt + 1;
    _sWts = Mat::zeros(n, 1, DataType<float>::type);
    _sDone = Mat::zeros(n, 1, DataType<int>::type);
    _sMap = Mat::zeros(n, 1, DataType<int>::type);
    _sIds = Mat::zeros(n, 1, DataType<int>::type);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) _sDone.at<int>(0, i) = -1;
    _sId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing in the src file it is required to rebuild the OpenCV library and link it to the project.